# Sequence and Series: Find the sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$f(r)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}....+\frac{1}{r}$ and $f(0)=0$, then value of $$\sum_{r=1}^n(2r+1)f(r)$$

(A) $n^2f(n)$

(B) $(n+1)^2f(n+1)-\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$

(C) $(n+1)^2f(n)-\frac{n^2+n+1}{2}$

(D)$(n+1)^2f(n)$

I googled and found that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}....+\frac{1}{r}$ cannot be  exactly calculated (but approximations exist, but the answer is not from approximations) so there has to be some way to reduce $$\sum_{r=1}^n(2r+1)f(r)$$ into solvable form, but I cannot figure out how, how to get the answer. The answer given is B.

Comment: @Martin R ,Thought it matches some part of my question, but it doesn't have satisfactory answer (a clear and easy to understand answer is appreciated by all, but it has only hints to solve and a mess of calculation, not like catchy answers given below. I would rather say, you should connect that question to mine because it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:

$$f(r+1)=f(r)+\frac{1}{r+1}\Rightarrow (r+1)^2f(r+1)=(r+1)^2f(r)+r+1$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{r=1}^n(2r+1)f(r)&=\sum_{r=1}^n[(r+1)^2f(r)-r^2f(r)]\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n[(r+1)^2f(r+1)-r^2f(r)-r-1]\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n[(r+1)^2f(r+1)-r^2f(r)]-\sum_{r=1}^n(r+1)\\
&=(n+1)^2f(n+1)-1f(1)-\sum_{r=1}^n(r+1)\\
&=(n+1)^2f(n+1)-\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}\end{aligned}$$